# Transpose simple single column 3-row results into single row, 3-column one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a statistical query that would return three rows (as I have 3 types by which I group by), I also know the order of the rows as I do explicit `ORDER BY FIELD`:

`SELECT COUNT(id) AS c FROM Vehicles GROUP BY VehicleTypeID ORDER BY FIELD(VehicleTypeID, 1,2,3)`

Is there a simple way to transpose the rows into columns? Something like **(PSEUDO SQL)**:

```
SELECT c[0] AS CarsCount, c[1] AS MotorcyclesCount, c[2] AS TrucksCount FROM (
     SELECT COUNT(id) AS c 
     FROM Vehicles 
     GROUP BY VehicleTypeID 
     ORDER BY FIELD(VehicleTypeID, 1,2,3)
)
```

Comment: You could probably use a PIVOT table. See this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: This is MySQL, by looking at the syntax, I'm not sure there is corresponding way to do it with MySQL.

Comment: In MySQL (which I assume you use), there is no 'simple' way. There are complicate ways, none of which I've seen were better then a little application-level handling (MS SQLserver is better at that point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a `case` statement with aggregation:

```
SELECT max(case when fieldnum = 1 then c end) AS CarsCount, 
       max(case when fieldnum = 2 then c end) AS MotorcyclesCount, 
       max(case when fieldnum = 3 then c end) AS TrucksCount
FROM (SELECT COUNT(id) AS c , FIELD(VehicleTypeID, 1,2,3) as fieldnum
      FROM Vehicles 
      GROUP BY VehicleTypeID 
     ) t;
```

Comment: I've accepted this, but I did it on application level as it's uglier and much less readable this way.